# Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket'

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and wish to use websockets. When I created a Websocket object and tried to send on it, I was getting the following error:

```
InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
```

So I have solved this using the closure below. Is this a reasonable approach to solving my problem? Is there a better approach? One issue with my approach would be if someone later were to reassign the value of `ws.onopen`. I'm using redux so I will want to use my send when dispatching requests to the backend. I am also using ES6, webpack and node.js.

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org/");
ws.onmessage = msg => console.log(msg);

const send = (()=>{

    const queue = [];
    ws.onopen = () => queue.forEach(msg => ws.send(msg));

    return (msg) => {
        if(ws.readyState === ws.OPEN){
            ws.send(msg);
        }
        else{
            queue.push(msg);
        }
    };

})();

send("foo");
send("bar");
```

Comment: did you have a look at [Writing WebSocket client applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Sending_data_to_the_server) from the MDN? I think your `InvalidStateError` was because you didn't use the `onopen` event handler at first?

Comment: @Simon Hänisch Yes, and I am basing my solution on this.

Comment: I think you have the `(msg)` argument in the wrong function. If you pass it to `send()`, it actually gets passed to the returned function, not the self-calling anonymous function. It should be `const send = (() => { //...` and `return (msg) => { // ...`, right? Regarding your question about `ws.onopen` being reassigned, you could [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) your `ws` object to prevent that.

Comment: @Simon Hänisch Thanks for your feedback. I have fixed my question to reflect your comment.